# Can I replace the engine of a 3.7L Liberty with that of a different year?

Tags: jeep, engine-swap

My Jeep Liberty 2010 3.7L engine broke down and I was wondering if I could replace it with the engine of a Jeep Liberty 2003 3.7L.

I heard there can be trouble with the computer, what kind?

Thanks for the comments, I'll add that I personally have no experience, but I'd be doing that with someone who successfully did an engine swap in the 80s. He says it's not gonna be a problem, but I'm thinking that things are not like it was back then.

Comment: Probably useful to know how experienced you are in this sort of thing - generally "can it be done" is a yes, but the difficulty may be high. I mean folks have put Lamborghini engines in VW Golfs. So can you add some definition.

Comment: Fundamentally they're the same engine - the Powertech V6 so it's not a ridiculous notion. But I'm not sure it will be a simple plug and play swap - IIRC there were some changes to it around 2005 that affected cam profile and compression ratio and post '06 cars had drive by wire throttle rather than the mechanical throttle body of the early ones.